# How can I force Chrome Webrtc to send red instead of vp8

Tags: google-chrome, webrtc, sdp, vp8

I would like to send VP8 video trafic from Chrom browser ( using WebRTC ) to native C++.

I am using SDP with only VP8/90000 configuration, still chrome sends back RED/90000.

Is there an easy way to force Chrome to send VP8 only?

EDIT:
I have full control over the JavaScript webpage. 
Native C++ software creating SDP with VP8 (which been sent to JavaScript webpage)
And I want to send VP8 bi directional.

Comment: who is sending the offer? Chrome or your native app? Do you control the Chrome client(you writing the JS)? Also, your title seems to conflict with your question. Do you want media to stream RED or VP8?

Comment: Can you post both the SDP offer you pass into chrome and resulting answer it forms?

Answer (score 0):

If the C++ is generating the offer, just include VP8.  Chrome *shouldn't* add new "codecs", but if it does, just ignore them.  (RED is for redundancy/FEC)